# WebHostBuilder() no inicia. C# Integration Test

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, test

Estoy intentando crear una serie de test contra un servicio Asp.net core. El servicio inicia perfecto como así también los test corriendo contra este. El problema es cuando intento iniciar el los test usando webHostBuilder. Al momento de hacer la request obtengo el error:

> System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (String
>   reference not set to an instance of a String.
>       Parameter name: s)

. Desde la clase startUp del servicio

StartUp ->

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using TrackerBackend.Core.Middleware;

namespace serviceName
{
    public class Startup
    {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
        services.AddMvc();
        Ioc.AddRegistration(services, Configuration);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
          if (env.IsDevelopment())
          {
              app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
          }

          app.UseAuthentication();
          app.UseMvc();
      }
   }
}
```

Asi estoy creando el cliente ->

```
public Client()
{
    _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>());
    _client = _server.CreateClient();
    _client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:58255");
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias

Comment: si pones un breakpoint en constructor de Startup, ingresa?

Comment: si y he notado que donde le paso la configuración, llegan estos parametros {[environment, ]} {[urls, ]} {[applicationName, ServiceName]}
. Aparentemente environmet y urls llegan vacias , quizás desde ahi sale el ´String reference not set...´ pero no se de donde setearlas

Answer (score 0):

Resuleto

El webhostBuilder no toma por defecto el "appsettings.json"

```
_server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseEnvironment("Development")
            .UseContentRoot("path/rootProject")
            .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("path/appsettings.json").Build())
            .UseStartup<Startup>());
```